# How to maintain consistency in list?

Tags: python

I have a list like

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

I have a pop position list

```
 p_list = [0,3]
```

`[lst.pop(i) for i in p_list]` changed the list to `['b', 'c', 'd', 'f']`, here after 1st iteration list get modified. Next pop worked on the new modified list.

But I want to pop the element from original list at index [0,3] so, my new list should be

```
['b', 'c', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: Why are you doing this?  Why not use a dictionary where keys don't change?  Why not use a set where elements stand for themselves?

Comment: It looks a bit like you're not using the value of the list comprehension.  If you actually are storing it in a value and using it some, then that's ok, but if you are just using it to cleverly loop through the elements of `p_list`, then there is a much better python syntax for that:  the trusty `for` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lots of reasonable answers, here's another perfectly terrible one:

```
[item for index, item in enumerate(lst) if index not in plist]
```

Comment: This is the cleanest, clearest and quickest (and hence most pythonic) way of doing this.

Comment: Love list comprehension.  +1 for cleanest and clearest.  My $.02 is: for large plist if you call `pset = set(plist)` and then `[item for index, item in enumerate(lst) if index not in pset]` it is MUCH quicker for large plist sizes.

Answer (score 3):

You could pop the elements in order from largest index to smallest, like so:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
p_list = [0,3]
p_list.sort()
p_list.reverse()
[lst.pop(i) for i in p_list]
lst
#output: ['b', 'c', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the pops in reversed order:

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> p_list = [0, 3]
>>> [lst.pop(i) for i in reversed(p_list)][::-1]
['a', 'd']
>>> lst
['b', 'c', 'e', 'f']
```

The important part here is that inside of the list comprehension you should always call `lst.pop()` on later indices first, so this will only work if `p_list` is guaranteed to be in ascending order.  If that is not the case, use the following instead:

```
[lst.pop(i) for i in sorted(p_list, reverse=True)]
```

Note that this method makes it more complicated to get the popped items in the correct order from `p_list`, if that is important.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of modifying the list may be error prone, why not use `numpy` to only access the index elements that you want? That way everything stays in place (in case you need it later) and it's a snap to make a new `pop list`. Starting from your def. of `lst` and `p_list`:

```
from numpy import *

lst = array(lst)
idx = ones(lst.shape,dtype=bool)
idx[p_list] = False

print lst[idx]
```

Gives `['b' 'c' 'e' 'f']` as expected.

Comment: Numpy seems like an overkill dependency just to get views over lists.

Comment: @Inerdial Oh I wholeheartedly agree - though sometimes it's nice to see an alternate solution. I also tried to indicate why it might have it's advantages over other methods (re-usability, less accounting errors, etc...).